# Get certain information from Android Auto

Tags: android, android-auto

I'm starting to research about Android Auto, I want to do my thesis on this.

I want to know if it is possible to obtain from the Android Auto certain information that is important for the thesis project, such as:

- bluetooth connections,
- phone connections (identifiers, contacts, call logs, SMS),
- mass storage devices,
- and navigation infomation.

It is a project whose objective is to help researchers obtain important information in court cases.

I will be very grateful any information you can provide to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android Auto is really just another app, but enables a projected experience of the Android system to an Auto supported vehicle dashboard. Architecturally, what 3rd parties are allowed to build on is just a shell/template. The real activities etc are in the Android Auto process, and connected to the car.

When a 3rd party app is being shown, Android Auto just shuttles methods (onCreate, onResume, etc) back and forth between the processes. The information you’re asking about when used while Auto is connected would still be found through the mobile device and not independently within the Android Auto app itself.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was more or less what I thought, but I didn't finish understanding, that clarifies my mind a lot. I'm thinking to use a open source operative system like Automotive Grade Linux to do some experiments and see if I can obtain that information when a device connects to the OS, what do you think about that?